# Can I derive an IV as a segment counter for AES256-GCM?

Tags: encryption, aes, authenticated-encryption, gcm

I'm writing a software that will be encrypting & authenticating segments of data, each 4096 bytes long. These segments are saved to disk in a sequential order that will never change. So I was thinking to encrypt each one of them using `AES256-GCM`, but before I code it I need to confirm a couple of points:

1. To conserve space for saving an `IV` for `AES-GCM` encryption/decryption, I was thinking to use each of my segments' sequential number as an `IV`. Would that pose an issue (in cryptographic sense)?
2. I decided to go with a 16-byte `TAG` (that is used by `AES-GCM` for authentication.) Is that an overkill for an encrypted 4096 byte segment?

Comment: One more question to add: should the number also be included as AD data to bind it with the tag.

Comment: @eckes: Are you talking about an `IV`? Then, yes, the `IV` is included with the ciphertext and the `TAG` and sent via an open channel. Only the `key` should remain private.

Comment: I am talking about including the segment number into authenticated extra data (not only sending it). I mean I know that the sequence number must be authenticated to bind the message sequence and block reordering, the question is if using it as a IV does binding or if you need to specify it additionally as AAD.

Comment: @eckes: Oh, sorry, that's what you meant by AD. Well, the question is why would you want to include the segment counter in associated data?  The whole point of using it is that it's implied at decryption time, so it saves space. I don't think it will hurt if you included it though, but it kinda defeats the purpose. Otherwise then just use a randomly unique IV/`nonce` instead.

Comment: Include it to ensure it is not reordered: I guess my question is if the IV data is implicitly authenticated since it is used as a IV here as well

Comment: @eckes: Oh, no, the possibility of re-ordering segments will violate the use of segment indices. In that case the only way to go is the `nonce` for the `IV`. In that case for Windows I used [CoCreateGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688568(v=vs.85).aspx) to generate it. (You may want to SHA-1 it to make sure that no data about computer's MAC address is leaked.)

Comment: What I mean is: you must include the segment index into the authenticated data. It is either encrypted or added as additional authentication data. In those two cases you can recognize if the segment on position 2 is really the one you have written at that position. Using the position as IV might break the decryption so it is 'kind of' ensured, but afaik this is not a guarantee, so better provide it as additional authenticated data to GCM when encrypting and decrypting it.

Comment: @eckes: In my situation the segments cannot be re-ordered so the index is always implied and stays the same. That is why I decided to use this approach. If your data scheme allows re-ordering of segments, then, as I said above, you will save yourself a good deal of headache by using nonces instead. In that case you'll have to append IV to your ciphertext, but if you use segment indices you're also creating an additional headache of ensuring that the next IV is unique by scanning all existing segments. And adding index to plaintext data makes no sense as you will not see if before decryption.

Comment: Ok, last message: I mean malicious reordering by an attacker not supporting out of order messages. (And if you feed your index to aad it is seen before decryption)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58558/discussion-between-c00000fd-and-eckes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. To conserve space for saving an IV for AES-GCM encryption/decryption, I was thinking to use each of my segments' sequential number as an IV. Would that pose an issue (in cryptographic sense)?

No, it will not pose an issue because the (twelve byte) IV for GCM encryption is really a nonce; it is not directly used as counter for the underlying CTR encryption.

> 2. I decided to go with a 16-byte TAG (that is used by AES-GCM for authentication.) Is that an overkill for an encrypted 4096 byte segment?

The security of GCM is rather dependent on the size of the authentication tag. If you can spare the few bytes I would strongly recommend keeping it set to 128 bits. You have overhead anyway and 16 / 4096 (1 / 256 if I'm not mistaken) is less than half of a percent of overhead.

And it seems like you will be handling large amounts of data, which increases the attack surface to an attacker. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Although why are you saying that `IV` is 12 bytes. Isn't it the block size for `AES`, i.e. `128 bits`, or `16 bytes`?

Comment: The mode of operation determines the size of the IV / nonce. This is often the same as the block size for practical reasons. GCM performs pre-computation on the given IV, which has a usual size of 12 bytes. NIST SP 800-38D: "The IV is essentially a nonce, i.e, a value that is unique within the specified context, which determines an invocation of the authenticated encryption function on the input data to be protected." and "For IVs, it is recommended that implementations restrict support to the length of 96 bits, to promote interoperability, efficiency, and simplicity of design."

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. It doesn't just use "vanilla" AES. So what you're saying is that if I provide 128-bit IV, 32 will be discarded by the algorithm, right?

Comment: It will use another pre-computation to generate a 12 byte nonce, basically. It doesn't just discard the bytes. But (1) it will be less compatible and (2) it won't buy you any security and (3) it will cost you a very small amount of performance. AES itself is still the usual block cipher, but with GCM there are definitely other calculations going on that are more than just XOR as used for CBC mode yes.